# How to use responsive background image in css3 in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

I dont want to use html  tag. This is my css. I am using bootstrap 3.0.

```
background:url('images/ip-box.png')no-repeat;
background-size:100%;
height: 140px;
display:block;
padding:0 !important;
margin:0;
```

On 100% zoom this is OK. but when I zoom in at 180% approx, the image will be short from top and bottom, I want some css tricks.

Comment: is this what you're looking for?
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: what about media-queries???

Comment: @RitabrataGautam, yeap now i think media-queries is my last option... actually i dont knw about media queries, this is my first project on bootstrap.

Answer (score 73):

For full image background, check this:

```
html { 
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: you might need to reset the default bootstrap style to remove the white background:


body {
 background-color: transparent;
}

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Excellent!  Worked for me (bootstrap 4, Rails 5)

Answer (score 19):

You need to use `background-size: 100% 100%;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dSs9u/)

<s>[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/dSs9u/1/)</s> (Won't stretch, this is what you are doing)

Explanation: You need to use `100% 100%` as it sets for `X` AS WELL AS `Y`, you are setting `100%` just for the `X` parameter, thus the background doesn't stretch vertically.

---

Still, the image will stretch out, it won't be responsive, if you want to stretch the `background` proportionately, you can look for `background-size: cover;` but IE will create trouble for you here as it's CSS3 property, but yes, you can use CSS3 Pie as a polyfill. Also, using `cover` will crop your image.

Comment: i cant use width bcoz my design is responsive. If i use background-size: 100% 100%; the image stretchs vertically. This is nt good. is there any other option..??

Comment: @Faizan than go for jQuery

Comment: I really thought boostrap would be less pointless, unable to do basic stuff like this and with restricted sizes, probably would make more sense and generate less work to just write quality custom css.

Comment: background-size: 100% 100%; this works for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: What I needed was background-size: 100% auto;

Answer (score 9):

I found this:

**Full**

An easy to use, full page image background template for Bootstrap 3 websites

http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/full/

or

**using in your main div container:**

**html**

```
<div class="container-fluid full">


</div>
```

**css:**

```
.full {
    background: url('http://placehold.it/1920x1080') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check this out,

```
body {
    background-color: black;
    background: url(img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The file path `'images/ip-box.png'` implies that the css *file* is at the same level as the images *folder*.

It's probably more common to have 'images' and 'css' folders at the same level as the 'index.html' file.

If that were the case and the css file were one level down in its respective folder, then the path to `ip-box.jpg` as specified in the css file would be: `'../images/ip-box.png'`

Answer (score 1):

Set Responsive and User friendly  Background

```
<style>
body {
background: url(image.jpg);
background-size:100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
body {
  background-image:url(img/background.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height: 679px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```