# Bootstrap - add image responsiveness to CSS background image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

In Bootstrap, you can set the class of an  to resize with the viewport:

`<img src="..." class="img-responsive">`

How can I utilize Bootstrap with CSS background images?

`background: url(../images/MyImage.png) center center no-repeat;`

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612651/how-to-use-responsive-background-image-in-css3-in-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to your css code.

```
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try following css for full background:

```
img{
background: url(../images/MyImage.png) o-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```