# Boostrap background image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

May I ask how is it possible for me to get a properly bootstrap background image called bgImage. Currently, my background does not fit to the size of when the window is resized.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css/style.css"  rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="BGImage">
            <div class="container" id="tabcontainer">
                <div class="row">   
                //All the content i.e text field, text box are inside
                </div>      
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

## style.css

```
<body>
  background: none;
</body>
#BGImage {  
  background: url(../images/1.jpg) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;    
  background-repeat:no-repeat;  
  -webkit-background-size:cover;    
  -moz-background-size:cover;   
  -o-background-size:cover;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;   
  height:850px;
}
```

Comment: Maybe duplicate of: [How to use responsive background image in css3 in bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612651/how-to-use-responsive-background-image-in-css3-in-bootstrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this change your background-size to this,

```
#BGImage {  
  background-size:100% auto;
}
```

Comment: hi, this works :). But, there is still some space in between when i resized it. Is there any way to remove the white space?

Comment: If it's at top then that might be because of margin which you have added.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the direct answer to problem, because it tried to put your style inline. and so far it works fine

This is the simple code I use to implement.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\bootstrap.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
    <style media="screen">
      #BGImage {
        background: url('image/1.jpg') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
          background-repeat:no-repeat;
          -webkit-background-size:cover;
          -moz-background-size:cover;
          -o-background-size:cover;
          background-size:cover;
          background-position:center;
          height:850px;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist\js\bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="BGImage">
      <div class="container" id="tabcontainer">
        <div class="row">
          //All the content i.e text field, text box are inside
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Maybe from here it may help you figure out the problem

Comment: no, it doesn't work. It only displays half the image when i resize the window

Comment: Maybe you should check the parent style, it may affect on div#BGImage

Comment: the current parent style is the body. But body only has:
body {
 margin-top: 22px;
 background: none;
}

Answer (score 0):

You gave your image a height of 850 px. This isn't a responsive size. Change it to 100% so that it will fit the whole screen. Something like this:

Height: 100%;

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right, but You should do one more thing:

Use some content on the background `image(Like h1, p, button)` and use `padding/margin` to manage it. If you need, you can use some media query for mobile and tablet.